# Update Picasa 3.8 from Picasa 3.5 in Ubunt

Tags: ubuntu, updates, picasa

I have installed `Picasa 3.5` in ubuntu by some of the ways mentioned [here](http://www.google.com.hk/search?hl=zh-TW&q=picasa+3.5+wine&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=), I wonder if similar can be done for installing `Picasa 3.8`? Anyone tried this before? If yes, what will happen to the facetag (facial recognition) already present in `Picasa 3.5`?

Answer (score 1):

Did you read : http://www.webupd8.org/2010/04/how-to-install-picasa-36-in-ubuntu.html

Picasa for Ubuntu is basically a windows install of Picasa running in a custom install of wine (allowing system wide access).  The webupd8 article describes how to install the official version of Picasa, do a default "user" install of Picasa with a newer version (which is not supported by the officiial installer yet) then copy the newer user install over the older official one.

As an added bonus, many Ubuntu users are finding that this process fixes a bug that crept in during the roll out of Google+ as documented  on the [Picasa Forums](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Picasa/thread?tid=069d2a8e9225fd4c&hl=en&fid=069d2a8e9225fd4c0004ae123fe0c958).

Comment: Answers that only provide a link are not particularly useful, and potentially expose the site to linkrot. Could you please add some detail to your answer so that it is directly useful?

Comment: Used this details in this link to go from 3.0 to 3.8 easily and flawlessly. Everything from 3.0 transferred without a problem so I can only guess that the face data would do so as well.